# How to change tip position for specific index in foundation joyride?

Tags: javascript, php, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

Hi guys i want to change the position of tip in Tour according to the my index

for example i want to change the position of tip when index is 4

**current output is** 
[image]

**required:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you want to change your attached element from the user icon to the drill-down select. 
like

```
<li data-id='XXXXX your select id' data-button='Next' data-prev-text='Prev' class='top-bar' data-options='tipLocation:left;tipAnimation:fade'>
```